# How to count 1s in binary using table lookup and XOR?

Tags: javascript, bitwise-operators, lookup-tables

I need to count the number of 1s in a binary representation of an integer.
The two requirements are:

1) Must use table lookup
2) Must use XOR bitwise operator

So far, I think I have a table lookup that would work:

```
const generateLookupTable = (int) => {
  const range = Array.from({length: int}, (x,i) => i);
  const toBinary = (table, i) => {
    const binary = (i >>> 0).toString(2);
    table[i] = binary;
    return table;
  }

  const lookupTable = range.reduce(toBinary, {})
  return lookupTable;
};
```

This prints out something like:

```
generateLookupTable(7)
{0: "0", 1: "1", 2: "10", 3: "11", 4: "100", 5: "101", 6: "110"}
```

I'm stumped on how I would use XOR to solve this problem (or why I would even use a lookup table). I feel like I could solve this easily by converting the int to a binary and then just looping through each character and summing up the 1s I see. However, the requirements are making it difficult.

Comment: Not the first time requirements got in the way of good design.

Comment: This feels like the quality problem a great education provides /s

Comment: `const totallyUsed = {}[0^0];`, then do the code. "Must use" is just ridiculous, what counts as "use"? If it is some completely forced use that serves no other point, i think think the before mentioned does the job.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Efficiently count the number of bits in an integer in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43122082/efficiently-count-the-number-of-bits-in-an-integer-in-javascript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is only a partial hint, but it was too long for a comment. One of the things you can do with XOR is find the rightmost 1. You could then subtract this and do it again while keeping a count. This would tell you how many ones are in a number::

```js
function countOnes(n) {
    let count = 0
    while(n > 0) {
        n -= n ^ (n & (n -1))
        count++
    }
    return count
}

let n = 1709891;
console.log(countOnes(n))
console.log(n.toString(2))

n = 7
console.log(countOnes(n))
console.log(n.toString(2))

n = 9
console.log(countOnes(n))
console.log(n.toString(2))
```

Maybe that's a little helpful. Not sure what the instructions are really after.

Comment: this looks like it works! would you mind explaining `n -= n ^ (n & (n -1))` ? i don't get 1) why you subtract from n 2) why you subtract 1 from n 3) what & and ^ do in this case

Comment: towards finding bits in a number, there are tons of approaches - there is also the macro compacted table approach, but it doesn't use xor. There are others, which use xor somewhere on the line, but don't need a lookup table. One can e.g. forcefully use xor in the table method, but it's more of a joke then.

Comment: @Edmund if you are interested in learning more about bitwise operations in JavaScript give the MDN a documentation a read. Also keep in mind that casting something to a string is infinitely slower then a bitwise operation.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators

Comment: If one were to just implement it without restrictions, use this: `const countBits = n => { n = n - ((n >>> 1) & 0x55555555); n = (n & 0x33333333) + ((n >>> 2) & 0x33333333); return ((n + (n >>> 4) & 0xF0F0F0F) * 0x1010101) >>> 24; };` - see http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html (Counting bits set). Also note that WebAssembly offers access to the SSE instruction `__popcnt`, but WebAssembly to Javascript interop always has a lot of overhead, so it is not faster, when used primarily in JS. But all that is not what the question is about, it has those weird "must use" additions.

Comment: @Edmund `^` is XOR and `&` is bitwise AND. It's easiest to go through small numbers and watch the bits. For example starting with 6 `110` `&` 5 `101` gives you `100`. XOR that with the 6 gives you `10` or 4 the right most bit. Now subtract 4 from 6 which has the effect of removing the right most bit and do it again until you run out of bits.

Comment: That `n -= n ^ (n & (n -1))` could be written as `n ^= n & -n`, a bit simpler but still uses XOR

Comment: @ASDFGerte That code's from C, which is strongly typed.  In JS, you can get a significant speed boost by first coercing n to an int32 before the first operation, i.e. `n => { n = (n|0) - ...`.  I tested some variations here:  https://jsperf.com/fast-int32-bit-count