# Number of 1 Bits with Javascript

Tags: javascript

**Question**: Write a function that takes an unsigned integer and returns the number of '1' bits it has (also known as the Hamming weight).

**Example 1**:

Input: `n = 00000000000000000000000000001011`

Output: `3`

Explanation: The input binary string `00000000000000000000000000001011` has a total of three '1' bits.

**My Code**

```
var hammingWeight = function(n) {
    for (i=0; i<32; i++) {
        var mask = 1;
        var count = 0;
        if ((mask & n) != 0 ) {            
            mask <<= 1;
            count++;
        }    
        return count;
    }
};
```

**Test Case**:

```
00000000000000000000000000001011
00000000000000000000000010000000
11111111111111111111111111111101
```

**Expected Output**:

```
3
1
31
```

**Output**:

```
1
0
1
```

What did I do wrong with my code?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Efficiently count the number of bits in an integer in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43122082/efficiently-count-the-number-of-bits-in-an-integer-in-javascript)

Comment: Not the same approach but it's related to the subject. Thanks for suggesting!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a few issues here:

- You are redefining `count` and `mask` inside of your `for` loop.
- You are `return`ing after the first iteration of the loop, instead of waiting for the whole thing to count up.
- You only shift `mask` if a bit is `1`.

Here is a corrected function:

```
var hammingWeight = function(n) {
    var count = 0;
    var mask = 1;
    for (i=0; i<32; i++) {
        if ((mask & n) != 0 ) {            
            count++;
        }
        mask <<= 1;
    }
    return count;
};
```

Comment: Mask should also go with the count as well.

Comment: And to get correct results,  shifting the `mask` should be outside of the `if`

Answer (score 2):

A shorter way to write this could be:

```js
const hammingWeight = value => [...value].filter(f => f == 1).length;
```

Explanation:

`[...value]` this will create an array of 0's and 1's based on your string

`.filter(f => f == 1)` will filter the array, keeping only the 1 values

`.length` gives you the length of the filtered array